# id -u $var gives the same output if $var has a value or not

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, command

I'm writing a script to configure new debian installs while finding the best solution to confirming that a user exists in the script, the best way I found gives me wierd output.

**PROBLEM:**

`id -u $var` and `id -u $varsome` give the same output even though
   `var` has a value (the username) and `varsome` has no value

```
[19:49:24][username] ~ ~↓↓$↓↓ var=`whoami`
[19:53:38][username] ~ ~↓↓$↓↓ id -u $var
1000
[19:53:42][username] ~ ~↓↓$↓↓ echo $?
0
[19:53:49][username] ~ ~↓↓$↓↓ id -u $varsome
1000
[19:09:56][username] ~ ~↓↓$↓↓ echo $?
0
[20:10:18][username] ~ ~↓↓$↓↓ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Licens GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 eller senere <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
[20:27:08][username] ~ ~↓↓$↓↓ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I got the command from this question on stackoverflow: [Check Whether a User Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14811915/6372809)

**QUESTIONS:**

- What is happening here?
- Is there a better way you can find to verify a user exist's in a script?
- Pointers on the script well appreciated

Comment: Try it with a username *other* than yours.

Comment: Presumably `varsome` is empty so `id -u $varsome` is the same as `id -u`

Comment: @steeldriver That's sound's very enlightening

Comment: @ikkachu Thank's for the edit, much cleaner like this

Comment: @somethingSomething, yeah, I meant to comment about the cleanup... I think the main thing about `id` was there in the first part. If you have some particular part of the script you're struggling with, do ask. But it maybe better placed in a separate question.

Comment: ikkachu Thank you that's really reasuring heheh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the variable expansion wasn't quoted, the empty word that results from `$varsome` being expanded is removed completely.

Let's make a function that prints the number of arguments it gets and compare the quoted and non-quoted case:

```
$ args() { echo "got $# arguments"; }
$ var=""
$ args $var
got 0 arguments    
$ args "$var"
got 1 arguments
```

The same happens in your case with `id`: `id -u $var` is exactly the same as just `id -u` when `var` is empty. Since `id` doesn't see a username, it by default prints the current user's information.

If you quote `"$var"`, the result is different:

```
$ var=""
$ id -u "$var"
id: ‘’: no such user
```

With that fixed, you can use `id` to find if a user exists. (We don't need the outputs here though, so redirect them away.)

```
check_user() { 
    if id -u "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "user '$1' exists"
    else
        echo "user '$1' does not exist"
    fi
}
check_user root
check_user asdfghjkl
```

That would print `user 'root' exists` and `user 'asdfghjkl' does not exist`.

---

This is a bit of the inverse of the usual problems that come from the unexpected word splitting of unquoted variables. But the basic issue is the same and fixed by what half the answers here say: always quote the variable expansions (unless you know you want the unquoted behaviour).

See:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)
- [BashGuide on Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

Comment: @ikkachu Thank you so much it was driving me crazy this wierd logic, great answer

Answer (score 1):

The command `id -u` will give you the id of the current user. The command `id -u user` will give you the id of that user.

Now in your example, you use

```
var=`whoami`
id -u $var
```

The command `whoami` returns the current user. So `id -u current_user` will return the id of the current user, and `id -u` will also return the id of the current user.

**Edit**

Note that backticks are deprecated an it is recommended to write `$(whoami)` instead, for example:

```
var=$(whoami)
id -u $var
```

Comment: @RalfFriedl Thank you for the answer, yes this is true, but nothing new here, my point was that the variable that had no value was giving the same output

Comment: @somethingSomething Yes, and I explained why it gives the same output inyour case. If you already knew that, then what was the question?